# SQL prepared statements. PHP

Tags: php, sql

May be this question will be sort of "stupid-questions", but still...
I'm new to PHP and SQL and I can't understand what I am doing wrong here:

```
if(isset($_POST[$logButton])) //Checking for login button pressed
    {
        //Retrieving information from POST method
        $uid = $_POST['login'];
        $upwd = $_POST['password'];
        //SQL Connection
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'students');
        if(!$mysqli)
        {
            echo "<h1 class='h1A'>Problem accured while connecting to the DB. " . mysqli_error($mysqli) . "</h1>"; //!!!Delete displaying error msg after dev.
        }else
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM login_data WHERE login = ? AND password = ?"; //SQL query
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die("error1"); //No error
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $uid, $upwd) or die("error2");//No error

            $stmt->execute() or die("error3");//Giving DB query. No error
            $result = $stmt->fetch() or die("error4".mysqli_error($mysqli)); //Putting query's result into assoc array. !!!Delete displaying error msg after dev. No error
            echo print_r($result); //It prints out "11" ? ? ?
            if(count($result['id']) < 1) //If no rows found.
            {
                echo "<h1 class='h1A'>Couldn't find account. Please, recheck login and password.</h1>";
                die();
            }elseif($result['id'] > 1)//If more then 1 row found.
            {
                echo "<h1 class='h1A'>Caught 9090 error. Contact the administrator, please.".mysqli_error($mysqli)."</h1>";
                die();
            }elseif($result['id'] == 1) //If only one row's been found.
            {
                $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
                redirectTo('/index.php'); //Declared function.
                die();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a part of handler function in lib.php file. This file is included to the html-page and the function is used. No errors displayed and when I print_r $result - it prints out 11. Can't get it.

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Thanks. I will use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, use *print_r* without *echo* :

```
print_r($result);
```

or pass second parameter to *print_r* function so it can return string:

```
echo print_r($result, true);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php for more info.